# TypeScript type definition for promise.reject

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

The following code is correct in terms of the type that is returned, because `then` always return the promise array.

```
Promise.resolve(['one', 'two'])
.then( arr =>
{
  if( arr.indexOf('three') === -1 )
    return Promise.reject( new Error('Where is three?') );

  return Promise.resolve(arr);
})
.catch( err =>
{
  console.log(err); // Error: where is three?
})
```

TypeScript throw error:

> The type argument for type parameter 'TResult' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>     Type argument candidate 'void' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'string[]'.

But in reality, `then` never will return `void`.

I can explicitly specify type `.then<Promise<any>>`, but it's more like a workaround, not the right solution.

How to write this right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not return `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` *inside* a promise chain. The `resolve` should be driven by simple return and `reject` should be driven by an explicit `throw new Error`.

```
Promise.resolve(['one', 'two'])
.then( arr =>
{
  if( arr.indexOf('three') === -1 )
    throw new Error('Where is three?');

  return arr;
})
.catch( err =>
{
  console.log(err); // Error: where is three?
})
```

## More

More on promise chaining https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/promise.html

Comment: As a best practice, of course you are right, but at the same time there is no reason why you could not return `Promise.resolve()` and/or `Promise.reject()` from within a `then` handler, and the OP has a legitimate question as to why TypeScript is unhappy about that.

Comment: What is the reason why "you should not return `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject`"? I don't understand why anyone would consider that "a best practice". Chainability is at the core of promises, and it's a great principle. Why would you throw an exception that will be converted into a rejected promise instead of creating the rejected promise yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Typescript is complaining about the difference in return type between your `Promise.reject` return value (`Promise<void>`) and your `Promise.resolve` value (`Promise<string[]>`).

Casting your `then` call as `.then<Promise<void | string[]>>` will let the compiler know of the union return type.

as @basarat notes, you should just throw an error instead of using Promise.reject (which will be passed to whatever catch handler is provided).