# TypeScript Async Returning/ Throwing Errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, es6-promise, typescript-typings

When you make a function async it implicitly always returns a Promise.

Firstly, when using an `async` function is there actually any difference between returning

`Promise.reject(new Error(...))` vs `throw new Error(...)`

Should you use one over the other for reasons other than consistency in the code base?

---

Secondly, what type does it return?

Based on VS Code `Promise.reject(new Error(...))` returns a `Promise<Never>` does `throw new Error(...)` return the same thing?

---

Thirdly, should you change the functions type signature to Promise in the case it can return a rejected Promise? Is there a rejected Promise type? Does this even make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post

Comment: 1) [they're the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33445415/1048572) 2) `throw` probably has a `void` type, however it might not have one at all because it's a statement not an expression - the same is true for `return` 3) Yes, it makes sense, but TypeScript didn't do it because they thought it would be too complicated

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7588 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6283 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381940/typescript-type-definition-for-promise-reject